# Merging 6 tables having same columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 6 tables with columns cust_id and cust_preference. I need to merge the information from these 6 tables under one such that I am able to view which of the cust_ids have multiple preferences. I am getting confused as to which table should I take as the base table and how the query would look like? Also, would it make any difference in the query if it is run in BIG Query?

I used UNION ALL

**Example with 3 tables below**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmxgf.png)

**Expected Outcome**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AchJk.png)

Comment: Can you please add more details to the question, as it is difficult to understand your use case? Make sure to add the sample tables and data.

Comment: Are you after *union*?

Comment: The cust_preference information is different in each table, while the cust_id can be same or different across tables. It's like understanding for eg: whether customer from table A that has preference as road trips, is present in Table B as well or not, that has preference as skiing.

Answer (score 2):

Identical Tables (why do you have them anyway) are joined vertically by UNION

So you get

```
 SELECT col1, col2,col3 FROM a1
UNION 
 SELECT col1, col2,col3 FROM a2
UNION
 SELECT col1, col2,col3 FROM a3
UNION
 SELECT col1, col2,col3 FROM a4
UNION
 SELECT col1, col2,col3 FROM a5
UNION
 SELECT col1, col2,col3 FROM a6
```

This would also remove all duplicates, if there are any.

The Order is irrelevant, and you can take the unioned table to sort or Group data as you need it

Comment: Thank you so much. The cust_preference information is different in each table, while the cust_id can be same or different across tables. It's like understanding for eg: whether customer from table A that has preference as road trips, is present in Table B as well or not, that has preference as skiing.